# If $X\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu = 1,\sigma = 4)$ find $\textbf{P}(X^2 - 2X \leq 9)$

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, density-function

If $X\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu = 1,\sigma = 4)$ find $\textbf{P}(X^2 - 2X \leq 9)$.

I understand how to find the pdf of $X$, but I'm not sure how that would work for a function of $X$ like $X^2 - 2X \leq 9$.

Comment: Hint: The quadratic inequation will give you an interval. Then you have to compute the probability of that interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To begin with, notice that
\begin{align*}
x^{2} - 2x \leq 9 \Longleftrightarrow (x^{2} - 2x + 1) = (x-1)^{2} \leq 10 \Longleftrightarrow \left(\frac{x-1}{4}\right)^{2} \leq \frac{5}{8} = 0.625
\end{align*}

Therefore we have
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(X^{2} - 2X \leq 9) = \textbf{P}\left(Z^{2} \leq \frac{5}{8}\right) = \textbf{P}\left(-\frac{\sqrt{10}}{4} \leq Z \leq \frac{\sqrt{10}}{4}\right)
\end{align*}

where $\textbf{Z}\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Can you proceed from here?